# Keyup Event in case of dot CO & COM url Shorten

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, xmlhttprequest, keyevent

I'd love to know if there is a possibility to add a trigger ("KEY EVENT"ׁׂׂ) to avoid sending the request twice.

The problem is if we start typing in the URL field the domain http://www.example.com.. The AJAX will trigger on "http://www.example.co" and then again when you add the last letter.

There are an option to avoid that or give the user few second to finish to write the full domain?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function isUrl(url){
        var regex = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i;
        return regex.test(url);
}
function showHint(str) {
    if (!isUrl(str)) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a url in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
Url: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p><span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change the regex .

Comment: can you give me more details? @Mahi

Comment: so that it accept only `http://www.example.com`